# Positively invariant with respect to nonlinear dynamics

Tags: differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control

I have the set of nonlinear differential equations describing a system I modeled for my research (spread of epidemics or information for instance):

$$\begin{array}{rl} \dot{p}(t) &= \gamma r(t)-u(t)p(t)\\ \dot{q}(t) &= u(t)p(t)-\delta q(t)\\ \dot{r}(t) &= \delta q(t)-\gamma r(t)\end{array}$$

Since $\dot{p}+\dot{q}+\dot{r}=0$, I only consider the last two equations:

$$\begin{array}{rl} \dot{q}(t) &= u(t)(1-q(t)-r(t))-\delta q(t)\\ \dot{r}(t) &= \delta q(t)-\gamma r(t)\end{array}$$

with input $$u(t)\in \{{u}:u\textrm{ is Lebesgue integrable, } 0\leq u(t)\leq u_{\max}\}$$ and the set $$\Omega=\{(q,r)\vert 0 \leq {q},\,{r}\leq 1, {q}+{r}\leq 1\}$$

My goal is to show that $\Omega$ is positively invariant with respect to the nonlinear dynamical system expressed above, i.e., a solution starting from any initial condition $(q,r)\in\Omega$ remains confined to $\Omega$.

Edit: $p(t),\,q(t),$ and $r(t)$ represent probabilites that sum up to $1$: ${p}(t)+{q}(t)+{r}(t)=1$.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance,  but what does it mean "$\Omega$ is positively invariant with respect to the dynamical system .." ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou I believe it means that if the state is in $\Omega$ at $t_0$ then it stays in $\Omega$ for all $t \geq t_0$.

Comment: Thanks, @RodrigodeAzevedo, correct :) I tried to include some background information.

Comment: thank you for updating the post. It is certainly clear now.

Comment: This should be simple enough to prove if you draw $\Omega$. You need to show that the vector field is pointing "inwards" at the boundary $\partial\Omega$, for all possible values of control u. From equation for $\dot{q}$, it looks like  the term containing $u$ vanishes on part of $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: @PiyushGrover It's been a while since I took differential equations, what is exactly meant by vector field pointing inward or outward? (all I know is that it has something to do with calculating $\dot{q}$ and $\dot{r}$ along the boundary,i.e., along the axes $(0\leq q \leq1, 0),\, (0,0\leq r \leq1)$ and the line $q+r\leq 1$)

Comment: It means that the dot product of vector $(\dot{q},\dot{r})$ with the outward pointing vector $\hat{n}$  on boundary should negative.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Thank you so much, I think I completely get it now: dot product of the outward pointing normal vector of the boundary $\bigg(\hat{n}_1=(0,-1),\,\hat{n}_2=(-1,0)$, and $\hat{n}_3=(1,1)$ and the derivative vector $(\dot{q},\dot{r})\bigg)$. I would really appreciate it if you could also point me to your reference (if any); I did a lot of searching but didn't find one that would be this tractable.

Comment: Blanchini, Franco. "Set invariance in control." Automatica 35.11 (1999): 1747-1767.